# "needn't be answered" and "not needed to be answered"

Tags: sentence-construction, contractions

Is there a difference or a grammatical mistake in this two sentences?

> - All the questions needn't be answered
> - All the questions are not needed to be answered

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good example of how you can't just expand contractions to make your writing "more formal"; you often must also shuffle the words around and change verb forms or even verb choices.

*All the questions needn't be answered* is an acceptable informal way to express the concept that someone does not need to answer all of the questions.

*All the questions are not needed to be answered*, on the other hand, violates two rules of formal written English: you must use the helper verb *do not* rather than *are not* in this context, and you must use bare *need*, not *needed*.  Thus: *All the questions do not need to be answered*.

(*All the questions need not be answered* is also technically correct but nobody would write it that way today unless they were intentionally trying to sound old-fashioned.)

In both cases, I think the sentence also has a style problem: leading with *All the questions* is confusing, because "All the <noun> are not <predicate>" sounds ambiguous in English — do you mean "**not all** of the <noun> are <predicate>" or do you mean "**none** of the <noun> are <predicate>"?  (Some people will loudly insist that it can only mean "not all ..." but that doesn't make it not **sound** ambiguous.)  I would therefore write it differently:

informal: *You needn't answer all the questions.*
formal: *You don't need to answer all the questions* or *Not all of the questions need to be answered.*

(Even in prose that is so high-formal that you are supposed to actively avoid using contractions, I would still write *don't*, because in my head *do not* is reserved for the imperative.  Your copyeditor may disagree, in which case listen to them, not me.)

Comment: "All the questions are not needed to be answered" I'm not sure that this is as invalid as you claim. Plus all <noun> are not <predicate> can't be none. That's an entirely different sentence. The negation of a predicate is not the same as the negation of the qualifier

Comment: @eques (1) It is definitely invalid. There is no variety of English I know that will permit the use of _are_ instead of _do_ in this context, and _need_ instead of _needed_ is a basic tense-agreement issue. (2) Regarding "all [noun] are not", you are doing the thing that I said "some people" will do, and whether or not you agree that it _is_ ambiguous, it still _sounds_ ambiguous and should therefore be avoided.

Comment: 1). "You are not needed" Perfectly valid. In this case, we can view "needed" either as an adjective (the state of being required) or "are needed" as the passive of "to need" (Water is needed --> Someone needs water). This is quite elementary English. 2) And who besides you says it is ambiguous? English has ambiguities of course, but that is definitely not one.

Comment: Your assertions re (1) don't make any sense to me - you appear to be talking about some other sentence entirely, not the one the OP asked about - so let's just drop that part. Regarding (2), however, I never said it _was_ ambiguous.  I said it _sounded_ ambiguous and I stand on that assertion.

Comment: 1) You asserted that "are needed" is not grammatically possible, but it certainly is. I contrasted with generic grammar structures which are possible in English. You certainly can use "are" + "needed", which is what you are claiming to be impossible.

Comment: @eques I never made any claim about the general case.  I said _the OP's example sentence_ is incorrect because it should have been "do not need" instead of "are not needed" and again I stand on that assertion.

Comment: So "are not needed" is never valid? Google Ngrams  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22not+needed%22%2C%22does+not+need%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20not%20needed%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%22%20does%20not%20need%20%22%3B%2Cc0 finds lots of occurrences of "not needed". You do not assert that simply that sentence is ungrammatical. You assert that it violates  two rules: are vs does and needed vs need. But either a) those aren't rules or b) you are talking about more than just that sentence

Comment: I said that _that sentence_ violates two rules, I said nothing about what other sentences those rules might or might not apply to.

Comment: Yes, but those "rules" aren't rules.

Comment: "Questions are not needed" is valid. You can use are + needed. The original sentence is valid even if it's unlikely.

Comment: How do you expect me to respond to an assertion that rules are not rules?  Yes, they are rules. Yes, they apply to the sentence under discussion.  Yes, in _other_ contexts you can use are + needed, _but not this one_. This sentence requires "do not need".  (The presence of "not" is very important, as is the presence of a "to be ..." clause.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_inversion .)

Comment: What rule says you cannot use "are not" and "needed"? Either together or in this case. And what is special about this case that prohibits their use? That's what's missing. Your rules are not rules because all you said was that two rules were violated, namely that "does not" must be used in place of "are not" and "need" must be used in place of "needed" And you state "in this context". But provide no reason what is special about this context that this claimed rule would apply.

Comment: You haven't even given a coherent rule. Just a statement that one grammar form must be replaced with another, no statement of why or when. "to be needed" is a valid verb and "to need" is a valid verb. This is a case of a double passive.

Comment: Negative inversion is also inapplicable since that discusses whether phrases with negatives in them can be inverted to have the negative initially. It says nothing about whether passives are permitted or not.

Comment: Look, this is ELL, not ELU.  I am 100% certain that a native StdAmEng speaker would never say "all the questions are not needed to be answered", only "all the questions do not need to be answered".  I cannot _justify_ that intuition in terms that will make sense to anyone other than a linguist.  Do you want me to confuse the OP with a lot of babble about construction grammar?

Comment: The exact sentence is unlikely perhaps. But lots of similar ones are possible "You are not needed to be here before noon". Whether someone would likely say something is very different from whether they can say something. OP was asking about whether there was a difference in meaning not even whether they were valid (which they are).

Comment: Your answer already amounts to confusing learners with vague imprecise rules.

Comment: If they come away thinking that this type of sentence _always_ has to be written using "do not", that will be closer to the truth than whatever they thought before they asked the question.  And I'm done arguing with you.  If I can think of a way to explain the rule that will make sense to a beginner, I might edit it in later, but I doubt I will be able to come up with anything better than what's already there.

Comment: and what is this type of sentence? That's the point. You assert that you need "do not" but there's no applicable rule as far as I can see, so there's not even a rule some can learn. "The cakes are not baked" is not the same as "The cakes do not bake". "The water is not boiled" is similar to "The water does not boil" but not identical in all contexts

Answer (score 0):

> All the questions needn't be answered

This one is possible informally, but not super likely because typically in Modern English negatives are done using "do-support".

Thus:

> All the questions don't need to be answered

In this case, it indicates that not every question requires an answer (implying that some questions may be left unanswered)

> All the questions are not needed to be answered

This phrasing is uncommon, but not impossible.

In this case, the meaning of the two is approximately the same.

Answer (score -1):

First, the second one is not grammatically correct in English.  One cannot say "are not" in this situation; it should be "do not".  I have corrected it below and removed the -ed suffix from the verb "need" to correct it further:

> "All the questions **needn't be** answered."
>
> "All the questions **do not need** to be answered."

Your first one is very formal as you're using "need" as a "modal".  In Modern English, it is rare to hear or even see someone use "need" as a modal, especially these days.  The most common phrase I hear these days wherein "need" is normally used as a modal is in the examples below:

> "He **needn't** worry.  I'll take care of it all."
>
> "You **needn't** worry as long as you have me."
>
> "**Need** I **say** more?"
>
> "He **need only tell** the truth and nothing more."
>
> "You **need only do** what you're supposed to; I'll take care of the
>   rest."

There are other normal verbs that are sometimes used as modals in English, but many of them of phrasal modals; there is one main one, however, that isn't a phrasal one, which is "dare".  The other ones that have semi-modal status like "dare" are "ought (to)", "used to", "had better", "have to", "had to".  There are others as well; however, I am not going to list all of them, even though they are used often, because to do so is unnecessary:

> "How **dare he talk** back to me?  Who does he think he is?"
>
> "Sir Charles, you **dare resist**?"
>
> "I **dare not say**."
>
> "John had me so upset that he **dared not breathe** a word to me!

In other words, both are correct, but your first one that uses "need" as a modal is more formal; however, that doesn't make the second one informal in this case.  These are just two different ways to say the same thing and the second one is the regular way whereas the first one is really formal to the extent that I should dare call it "fancy-schmancy English"!